# Cut get request htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, get, url-rewriting

I need to redirect from the 1.html?somerequest url to 2.html (w/o request)

Here is my rewrite rule :

```
RewriteRule ^katalog/category/product/41-category/7865-productname.html?(.*)$ /katalog/category/product/41-category/7865.html [R=301,L]
```

but it redirecting me to 7865.html?request

Help me, please. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the rule to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/7865-productname.html$ $1/7865.html? [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: No, I need to redirect url katalog/category/product/41-category/7865-productname.html?something to /katalog/category/product/41-category/7865.html

Comment: of course. I was just waiting 6 minutes to accept your answer (carma limits))